# Define attributes of images generated by canvas2image e.g. alt tag

Tags: java, php, jquery, html

I am using the following code to convert html>canvas>image

```
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL('jpeg',1.0);
       $('.imagediv').html(image);
////This is just a snippet
```

My problem is that I want do define the other image attributes width,height,alt,class and a neat file name image.jpg. Like you can see, the image needs to be displayed in the browser on conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is really simple (and the answer is in the sample code that you added): just define the different attributes in the same way that you did the image source:

- `.src`: to specify the picture source.
- `.width`: to specify the element's width.
- `.height`: to specify the element's height.
- `.alt`: to specify an alternative text.
- `.title`: to specify the title.
- `.className`: to specify the class.
- `.id`: to specify the element id.
- etc...

Or if you want, you could use the `setAttribute()` method instead:

```
image.setAttribute("alt", "I am the alternative text");
```

Here is a simple demo of setting different attributes to an image generated using `canvas`:

```js
// get the canvas for manipulation
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw a square this is just a test
context.moveTo(5,5);
context.lineTo(395,5);
context.lineTo(395,195);
context.lineTo(5,195);
context.lineTo(5,5);
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.fillRect(5,5,390,190);
context.stroke();

// create the image and set the attributes
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('jpeg', 1.0);
image.alt = "A simple red rectangle with black border";
image.title = "Red rectangle with black border";
image.width = 400;
image.height = 200;
image.className = "myClass";

// place the image inside the div
document.getElementById('imagediv').appendChild( image );
```

```css
.myClass {
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<div id="imagediv"></div>
```

---

The only one that would be more complicated is the "neat file name". `toDataURL` method returns a data URI containing a representation of the image (in base64), and that's not a nice looking name. If you want to display a nice name, you will need to save the file and then point to it.

If what you want is a neat file name because the user will be able to download the picture using a link, what you can do is set the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute in the anchor and specify the name there.

Something like this:

```js
// get the canvas for manipulation
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw a square this is just a test
context.moveTo(5,5);
context.lineTo(395,5);
context.lineTo(395,195);
context.lineTo(5,195);
context.lineTo(5,5);
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.fillRect(5,5,390,190);
context.stroke();

// set the image as the href of the anchor
document.getElementById("myA").href = canvas.toDataURL('jpeg', 1.0);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<a href="" id="myA" download="Red rectangle with border.jpg">Download picture</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro for saving my career. Just what I needed